# How do I get the Service Manager in Zend Framework 2 beta4 to create an instance for album-table?

Tags: zend-framework2

This is the Rob Allen's Quick start Tutorial for Zend Framework beta4.

Error Message:Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for album-table

It seems like it fails trying to make a connection to the db, but I have not found way to tell.  It's uses a closure to return an instance from the ServiceManager, but gets the above error message.

module/Album/Module.php

namespace Album;

```
class Module
{
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                    __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                    'namespaces' => array(
                            __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                    ),
            ),
    );
}
public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}

public function getServiceConfiguration()
{

    $albumTable = array(
            'factories' => array(
                    'album-table' => function($sm) {
                        $dbAdapter = $sm->get('db-adapter');
                        $table = new AlbumTable($dbAdapter);
                        return $table;
                    },
            ),
    );      
    return $albumTable;
}
}
```

namespace Application;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter as DbAdapter,

```
class Module
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }
    public function getServiceConfiguration()
    {
            $factoryDBAdaptor = array(
              'factories' => array(
                 'db-adapter' => function($sm) {
                    $config = $sm->get('config');
                    $config = $config['db'];
                    $dbAdapter = new DbAdapter($config);
                    return $dbAdapter;
                 }, 
              ), 
           );
        return $factoryDBAdaptor;
    }    
}
```

config\autoload\global.php

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'PDO',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=zf2tutorial;hostname=localhost',
        'username'       => 'user',
        'password'       => 'password',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Hi w2wDev did you solved this issue, in case yes, would be helpful if you could share your solution

Answer (score 2):

It's related to the fact that Zend Framework's master has changed since Beta 4 and so my beta 4-targeted tutorial no longer works with latest ZF master.

Also, the SM may have previous exceptions, so you should check if there are any previous exceptions as that may show an underlying error.

**Update**
As of 11th July 2012, my [tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2-tutorial/) is now updated for Beta 5. It now uses the Db Adapter's ServiceFactory to create the adapter and so you don't even need to modify Application's Module class any more.

Comment: Apparently the problem is in the $dbAdapter = $sm->get('db-adapter'); line

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the main Module.php has a reference the getServiceConfiguration(). I had the same problem and had forgotten to include it.

module/Application/Module.php:

```php
<?php
namespace Application;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter as DbAdapter;
class Module
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getServiceConfiguration()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'db-adapter' => function($sm) {
                    $config = $sm->get('config');
                    $config = $config['db'];
                    $dbAdapter = new DbAdapter($config);
                    return $dbAdapter;
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: @Armand Im getting the same exact error, what w2wDev has posted. Any suggestions. My main Module.php has a reference to the getServiceConfiguration() as mentioned by you, but still getting the same error. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

update your composer.json file with following line.

```
"zendframework/zendframework": "dev-master#18c8e223f070deb07c17543ed938b54542aa0ed8"
```

run following commands you will be good to go.

```
php composer.phar self-update  
php composer.phar update
php composer.phar install
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this error by disabling toolbar. Just go to `config/autoload/zend-developer-tools.local-development` and set toolbar to false.

```
  'toolbar' => [
            /**
             * Enables or disables the Toolbar.
             *
             * Expects: bool
             * Default: false
             */
            'enabled' => false,
```