# ServiceNotFoundException in ZendFramework 2, example from Rob Allen

Tags: zend-framework2

for the past few weeks I have been following ZF2 especially  [Rob Allen's 'Album' example](http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework-2.pdf) , I have created the example DB-'zf2tutorial' and example table-'album', which works fine fetching all the items when I use php-mysql, so problems with the data in the DB.

My local.php looks like this
**conﬁg.autoload/local.php:**

```
return array(
    'db' => array
    (
        'driver'         => "Pdo",
        'dsn'            => "mysql:dbname=zf2tutorial;hostname=localhost",
        'username'       => "user", //here I added my valid username 
        'password'       => "password", //here I added my valid password 
        'driver_options' => array
        (
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
        ),
    ),
);
```

Module.php 
**module/Album/Model.php

```
<?php
namespace Album;

use Album\Model\AlbumTable;

class Module 
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig() 
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig() 
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getServiceConfiguration() 
    {
        return array(

            'factories' => array(

                'album-table' => function($sm) //also tried this 'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm)
                {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('db-adapter');//also tried this $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $table = new AlbumTable($dbAdapter);
                    return $table;
                },
            ),
        );
    }  
}
```

I just wanted to check whether the zf2turorial/album works or not it does throw this error which is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355126/how-do-i-get-the-service-manager-in-zend-framework-2-beta4-to-create-an-instance) post here in stackoverlow.

The error which it is throwing is: 
**Additional information:
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException**

```
File:
..\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:392
Message:
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Album\Model\AlbumTable
```

I have followed ZF2 Beta 5 tutorial as well, but still encountering this problem. In case if anyone has a solution, please do share with us.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I'm currently struggling with this exact same issue.

Comment: @BrianKessler Have you find the solution i am still stuck :(

Comment: I had this same problem in this same tutorial today. For me, moving the db and service_manager dictionary [the tutorial asks us to add these in **global.php**] to my module's **(Album/config) module.config.php** did the trick.

Answer (score 6):

seems like somebody has forgotten to update the newest changes in zf2.

the solution:

the file module/Album/Module.php has to contain this content:

```
<?php

namespace Album;

use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ServiceProviderInterface;

class Module implements ServiceProviderInterface
```

then you have to rename

```
public function getServiceConfig()
```

to

```
public function getServiceConfiguration()
```

Comment: Zend has standarized all Configuration TO Config. `getServiceConfig()` indeed is correct! Update the Framework files to latest master which is RC2, you shouldn't find a single Configuration in it :)

Comment: I'm struggling with this same issue and have tried to get the config both ways, including making one function simply an alias to call the other, but it doesn't help. Nor did adding the use.

Comment: Using getServiceConfig() was the solution for me!

Comment: Now that ZF 2.1.3 is out, the `getServiceConfig()` is correct.  It just needs the `ServiceProviderInterface` lines.

Comment: By doing so i am getting this error Fatal error: Class Album\Module contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ServiceProviderInterface::getServiceConfig) in D:\projects\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\Module.php on line 54

Comment: 'Fatal error: Class Album\Module contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ServiceProviderInterface::getServiceConfig) in D:\projects\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\Module.php on line 54'

Comment: @curtisdf : I tried the above solution but I am getting this Error: 'Fatal error: Class Album\Module contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ServiceProviderInterface::getServiceConfig) in D:\projects\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\Module.php on line 69'

Comment: @IvovanBeek please let me know how you solved it.I tried both ways but no Luck :(

Comment: @FawadGhafoor Using the method getServiceConfig() in the class Application\Module or add 'service_manager' => array('factories' => array('album-table' => function ($sm) { // RETURN CLASS HERE }))

Answer (score 2):

public function getServiceConfiguration()  is not the correct function name

```
rename getServiceConfiguration() to getServiceConfig()
```

although it is not mandatory you should declare the class Module as

```
class Module implements ServiceProviderInterface
```

Comment: I'm struggling with this same issue and have tried to get the config both ways, including making one function simply an alias to call the other, but it doesn't help.  Nor did adding the implements.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but try to put the code into

conﬁg.autoload/**global.php**: like this way

```
return array(
    'db' => array(

        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=kd_tutorial;host=localhost',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                    => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: I'm struggling with this same issue and already had this code in my global.php ; it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: In that case i would say try this one..http://www.kdtips.co.nz/2012/10/13/zend-framework-2-database-interaction/

Answer (score 1):

I have encoutered the same problem when try to implement code follow zend tutorial. The main reason is order-folder

```
module
    ModuleX
        config
        src
            ModuleX //may be you forget this one
                Controller
                Factory
                Model
                ...
        view
        Module.php
```

in Module.php, getConfig(), getAutoloaderConfig() is enough to run

```
class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface{
public function getAutoloaderConfig(){
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}

public function getConfig(){
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify config/autoload/global.php  with following code:

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=YourDBName;host=localhost',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                    => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

and You should put your database credentials in config/autoload/local.php so that they are not in the git repository (as local.php is ignored):

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'username' => 'YourDBUsername',
        'password' => 'YourDBPassword',
    ),
);
```

If you want more details refer [link1](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html#using-servicemanager-to-configure-the-table-gateway-and-inject-into-the-albumtable) or [link2](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just got the same issue.

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Cache\Model\UniversityStorage
```

In my case the problem was, that PHPUnit could not find the key `Cache\Model\UniversityStorage` in the service manager (registry) because it's being added in the `Module` class of the `Cache` module and the `Cache` module was missing in the PHPUnit config file and was also not being loaded:

**/module/Application/test/phpunit.config.php**

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'Cache', // <- was missing
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            '../../../config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            'module',
            'vendor',
        ),
    ),
);
```

I've added the `Cache` module to the module list. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that within config/autoload/global.php the service is named "Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter" while within module/Album/Module.php it was searching for "Zend\Db\Adapter" (missing additional \Adapter).

Adding missing "\Adapter" within module/Album/Module.php like this fixed it for me.

```
                'AlbumTableGateway' => function($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
```

Answer (score 0):

In `module/Album/src/Album/Model/Album.php`, use instead:

`array('name' => 'striptags'),
array('name' => 'stringtrim'),`

See the above namespaces created by Zend at `vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Filter/FilterPluginManager.php`

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting similar error for different modules and the code seems jus right then ADD an entry in composer.json

"Album\": "module/Album/src/"

in autoload and autoload-dev section like this where Album is the name of your Module

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\": "module/Application/src/",
        "Album\\": "module/Album/src/"

    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "ApplicationTest\\": "module/Application/test/",
        "Album\\": "module/Album/src/"
    }
},
```

after this run "composer update" and reload the page. check if error is gone.